# How to set a negative message expectation with a verifying double in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to test the conditional call to `obj.my_method` in the following code:

```
def method_to_test(obj)
  # ...
  obj.my_method if obj.respond_to?(:my_method)
  # ...
end
```

`obj` can either be a `Foo` or a `Bar`. One implements `my_method`, the other doesn't:

```
class Foo
  def my_method; end
end

class Bar
end
```

My test is currently structured like this:

```
describe '#method_to_test' do
  context 'when obj is a Foo' do
    let(:obj) { instance_double('Foo') }
    it 'calls my_method' do
      expect(obj).to receive(:my_method)
      method_to_test(obj)
    end
  end

  context 'when obj is a Bar' do
    let(:obj) { instance_double('Bar') }
    it 'does not call my_method' do
      expect(obj).not_to receive(:my_method)  # <- raises an error
      method_to_test(obj)
    end
  end
end
```

The first example passes but the second raises an error when setting the negative message expectation because `obj` is a verifying double that does not implement `my_method`:

```
#method_to_test
  when obj is a Foo
    calls my_method
  when obj is a Bar
    does not call my_method (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) #method_to_test when obj is a Bar does not call my_method
     Failure/Error: expect(obj).not_to receive(:my_method)
       the Bar class does not implement the instance method: my_method
```

I fully understand why RSpec raises this error. How can I test the line despite `obj` being a verifying double?

PS: I've enabled [`verify_partial_doubles`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/partial-doubles), so changing `instance_double('Bar')` to `object_double(Bar.new)` or just `Bar.new` doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting and tricky question! From the Rspec docs, I found this:

[edit: just saw you already understand why rspec complains, so you can jump to the **Possible Dirty / Less Dirty Solutions** parts. I'll keep the explanations I found here in case anyone else face a similar issue (and please correct me / add further info on that!)]

> Verifying instance doubles do not support methods which the class reports to not exist
>   since an actual instance of the class would be required to verify against. This is commonly
>   the case when method_missing is used.
>    - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/dynamic-classes

The docs cite issues with instance_double and the usage of method_missing, but I believe it's the same issue you're facing. Your Bar class does not **report to respond to :my_method**. In fact, in the failing test, `method_to_test(obj)` never gets called, as the test fails when you **try to define an expectation on the instance_double**:

```
describe '#method_to_test' do
  context 'when obj is a Bar' do
    let(:obj) { instance_double('Bar') }

    it 'does not call my_method' do
      puts "A"
      expect(obj).not_to receive(:my_method)  # <- raises an error
      puts "B"  # <- never runs
      method_to_test(obj)
    end
  end
end
```

produces:

```
#method_to_test
  when obj is a Bar
A
    does not call my_method (FAILED - 1)
```

When you try adding your expectation, Rspec looks for the **list of methods that the Bar class reports to have defined**, and does not find `:my_method`, and fails preventively, thinking it's actually helping you to identify an issue in your tests (after all you're trying to add a method call expectation on something that does not exist, so it's likely a typo, right? - ouch!).

**Possible Dirty Solution**

So, I'm afraid there is no consistent way to add this expectation to the instance_double you're using without dirty trickery. You could for example actually **define `:my_method` on Bar** so that you would be able to add the message expectation, but then you would have to redefine `respond_to?` in the context of Bar, resulting in something like this:

```
def my_method
  raise # should never be executed in any case
end

def respond_to?(m_name)
  m_name != :my_method && super(name)
end
```

But why would you want to do that? This is dirty and counter-intuitive! This type of strategy can work on the very specific case we're talking about, but this would couple your tests a lot to your specific implementation and **void their value as documentation**.

**Possible Less Dirty Solutions**

So, my suggestion would be to not rely on method expectations, but on the desired behavior. What you want is that the execution of `method_to_test(obj)` do not raise an exception because of a method missing on a Bar instance. You can accomplish it this way:

```
describe '#method_to_test' do
  context 'when obj is a Bar' do
    let(:obj) { instance_double('Bar') }

    it 'does not call my_method' do
      expect { method_to_test(obj) }.not_to raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

The downside is that if any exception is raised when executing the method body, this test will fail, while, ideally, we would want it to fail **only when a `NoMethodError` is raised**. You may try this, but it won't work:

```
    it 'does not call my_method' do
      expect { method_to_test(obj) }.not_to raise_error(NoMethodError)
    end
```

The reason is that the error raised in case `:my_method` is called on obj will not be of type `NoMethodError` but of type `RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError`:

```
#method_to_test
  when obj is a Bar
    does not call my_method (FAILED - 1)

Failures:

  1) #method_to_test when obj is a Bar does not call my_method
     Failure/Error: expect { method_to_test(obj) }.not_to raise_error
       expected no Exception, got #<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<InstanceDouble(Bar) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :my_method with (no args)> with backtrace:
```

You could use `RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError` instead of `NoMethodError` for the expectation, but that would also create fragile tests: what if you change your test Bar instance into a real obj instead of an instance_double, which would raise `NoMethodError` if `:my_method` was called? This test would keep passing while not testing anything worth at all. Also (as pointed out in comments), if you do this, RSPEC will warn you:

> "WARNING: Using expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass) risks false positives, since literally any other error would cause the expectation to pass, including those raised by Ruby (e.g. NoMethodError, NameError and ArgumentError), meaning the code you are intending to test may not even get reached. Instead consider using expect {}.not_to raise_error. This message can be supressed by setting: RSpec::Expectations.configuration.warn_about_potential_false_positives = false."

So, between these options, I'd **not** specify the type of exception.

**Possible (Best) Solution**

Finally, I'd suggest refactoring. Using `respond_to?` is usually an indication that you're lacking a proper interface to be defined and implemented across these multiple classes. I can't help on the specifics of this refactoring as that would be highly dependent of your current code context / implementation details. You should however evaluate if its worth cost-wise, and if it is not I'd suggest extracting `obj.my_method if obj.respond_to?(:my_method)` into a dedicated method call, so that asserting it would not raise_error would be a more reliable assertion, given you'd have less context where strange exceptions could be raised. Also, if you do this, you can pass a simple `double` object that would allow you to add message expectations the way you initially intended to.

Sorry for the --verbose answer :D

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Regarding the "Possible Dirty Solution" - that would be very implementation specific. I could change my code to something like `if obj.is_a?(Foo)` and the test would fail without a good reason.

Comment: Regarding the "Possible Less Dirty Solutions" - unfortunately, that results in: *"WARNING: Using `expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass)` risks false positives, since literally any other error would cause the expectation to pass, including those raised by Ruby (e.g. NoMethodError, NameError and ArgumentError), meaning the code you are intending to test may not even get reached. Instead consider using `expect {}.not_to raise_error`. This message can be supressed by setting: `RSpec::Expectations.configuration.warn_about_potential_false_positives = false`."*

Comment: And regarding the "Possible (Best) Solution" - extracting that line into a method to test it in isolation seems like the cleanest option, test-wise.

Comment: Nice  comments. @Stefan , I'll also update the answer with the Warnings! Thanks